# Lambda to collect properties in a child object

Tags: java, lambda

I have a class:

```
public class ProductInvoice {
     //Some other properties.
    private List<ProductEntry> productEntries = newArrayList();
//otherMethods
}
```

And:

```
public class ProductEntry {
//other properties
    private Long quantity;
    private Long productId;
}
```

Now  I need to prepare a map of `productId` vs quantity by iterating over a collection of `ProductInvoice` objects:

```
List<ProductInvoice> entries = productInvoiceRepository.findByProductEntries_ProductIdIn(productIds);
        Map<Long, Long> productIdVsQuantity = newHashMap();
        entries.forEach( pi -> pi.getProductEntries().forEach(pe -> {
            if (productIdVsQuantity.containsKey(pe.getProductId())) {
                productIdVsQuantity.put(pe.getProductId(), productIdVsQuantity.get(pe.getProductId()) + pe.getQuantity());
            } else {
                productIdVsQuantity.put(pe.getProductId(), pe.getQuantity());
            }
        }));
```

Could there be a better way of doing this? I think this can be optimized using better lambda usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use [`Stream.flatMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to convert a `Stream` of `ProductInvoice` to `ProductEntries`.

Next, you just need suitable `Collector` implementations to [sum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) all the quantities per product ID, and [group by](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) that...

Putting it all together:

```
Map<Long, Long> result = productInvoiceRepository
                            .findByProductEntries_ProductIdIn(productIds)
                            .stream().flatMap(v -> v.getProductEntries().stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductEntry::getProductId,
                                    Collectors.summingLong(ProductEntry::getQuantity)));
```

BTW, you may want to consider a better method name for `findByProductEntries_ProductIdIn()` to remove the underscore...

Comment: findByProductEntries_ProductIdIn() name actually just to add clarity for spring repository. the underscore (which is optional) adds clarity about product Id is present in child class.